# stop a loading gif from skipping while page loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, load, gif

I have a loading gif on my website that I want to spin while the iframes on my static site load. I have the gif load in doc ready while I hide everything else as things populate. Then on $(window).load I hide the gif and reveal the page.

Right now, this all works fine EXCEPT the gif stutters and skips while everything loads in the background. Is there a way to load and display the gif first while everything loads in the background so the skipping stops?

Currently it looks like this (#loading is the gif):

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
 $('#loading').show();
 $('#miniBar').hide();
 $('#MainLogo, #facebook').hide();
 $('.layout').css("margin-top","1000px");
 $('.layout').hide();
 $('#facebookTab').css('background','rgba(255, 255, 255, .5)');


//after content loads
  $(window).load(function(){
   $('#loading').fadeOut( function(){
    $("#myIcon").hide();
    $('#MainLogo').css({"margin-left":"-200px","width":"200px"}).show();
    $('.glyphicon').css({"left":"-300px"});
    $('#miniBar').css({"width":"0em", "left":"-50px"});

    $('#miniBar').show( function(){
      $(this).animate({"width": "16em", "left":"0px"}, 500);
      $('.glyphicon').animate({"left":"0px"},500);
      $('#MainLogo').animate({'margin-left':"0px"},500);
      $('.barText').animate({"left":"100px"},500);
    });
    });
});
```

Comment: Provided the loading element is on top of everything else there shouldn't be an issue with it stuttering. Can we see a live example?

Comment: I don't have a way to show a live example yet... but you do mean on top of the HTML in the body or on top of the js?

Comment: I mean inside the HTML itself. Not code wise, but element wise. So, you want the loading gif to appear above every other element on the page.

Comment: ultimately what is happening is document ready doesn't check to see if the iframes are filled, just present. So loading content in the Iframes is what is slowing the site down, thus the loading gif. But its also slowing down the gifs performance.

Comment: Yes it's at the top of the body. Only this above it is the <head> where I have my scripts listed.